# Python Regex take overlapping tags into account when finding matches

Tags: python, regex, xml, overlap

Regex always seems to be a tough topic when I'm exercising myself with Python. 
I got stuck when trying to extract all text between two tags. I came up with this piece of code:

```
m=re.compile('<div id="test">(.*?)<div id="test">', re.DOTALL).search(str(soup))
```

In this case, soup is a BeautifulSoup object of XML/HTML containing multiple occurrences of the  tag. The snippet I wrote provides me with matches, but not my intended. The regex finds all text between the provided tags, but I also want to obtain this for each tag, so with overlap taking place. 
Quite hard to explain, but I'll give a short example below:

```
<div id="test">
   text
</div>
<div id="test">
   more text
</div>
<div id="test">
   even more text
</div> 
<div id="test">..........
```

The output of my regex find should be: 
['text < /div>', 'more text < /div> ', 'even more text < /div>']

The output running with the wrong regex code would be only:
'text < /div>', because it would only iterate once over the starting and ending regex input.

Comment: Why don't do it with `BeautifulSoup`: `[div.get_text() for div in soup.select("div#test")]`?

Comment: If you do want to use a regular expression instead of @alecxe answer try this one `<div id="test">(.*?<\/div>)` [example](https://regex101.com/r/V0tDXu/1)

Comment: I managed to do it by utilising re.split()